# jQuery compare two serialized objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using a plugin that has an API for events `start` and `stop`. When I start dragging the element in the grid, It creates a serialized array of all the data in its current state.

When the item is dropped, it also creates a serialized array of data.

I want to compare these two sets of data to see if it has changed at all. I don't want to trigger a database call to update the grid placement if the user started dragging something and then put it back in its previous spot.

I have tried comparing them as is using `==` and I have also used `jSON.stringify` on them first before comparing but have read that it could provide mixed results.

Is there an easy to way to compare two objects like this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`==` checks if object's references are equal (doesn't compares content).

For deep object comparison, you can use [lodash's isEqual()](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind some inelegance, you could do something like this:

```js
var obj1 = [{x:1},{x:2}];
var obj2 = [{x:1},{x:2}];
var obj3 = [{x:1},{x:3}];


function isSameObject(o1, o2) {
   return JSON.stringify(o1) == JSON.stringify(o2);

}

alert('is same obj 1 and obj 2?' + isSameObject(obj1, obj2));
alert('is same obj 1 and obj 3?' + isSameObject(obj1, obj3));
```

Comment: This work just fantastic good men, thank you!