# Validate if two serializeArray in jsp have same values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have some checkboxes with some loaded values from DB, in UI before submitting the form i want to check if the checkboxes have same values or are unchanged.
For this I have variables one I am defining at the beginning of page loading

```
existingform=$('input[name=products]').serializeArray();
```

and the other variable whenever changing the values in the checkbox list named as "products"

```
var newform = $('input[name=products]').serializeArray();
```

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work

```
if(existingform === newform)
```

How can i validate if these two have same values?

Comment: Did you already check this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288240/jquery-compare-two-serialized-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify`.

```js
$('input[name=products]').val('foo');

var existingForm = JSON.stringify($('input[name=products]').serializeArray());

$('button').on('click', () => {
  var newForm = JSON.stringify($('input[name=products]').serializeArray());

  console.log(existingForm === newForm);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="products"/>

<button>Check if same</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify`.

```
if(
  JSON.stringify(existingform.sort()) ===
  JSON.stringify(newform.sort())
);
```

I'm also sorting the array before stringifying just in case.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The better approach would be to fetch the value from database, unserialize and compare it.

Other alternates are to save the previous value in the form with hidden element and compare in your backend.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 if(JSON.stringify(existingform) === JSON.stringify(newForm))
```